# Removed all my bash files in home directory (.zsh, etc.). What to do?

Tags: bash

By accident ran `sudo rm *.` in the home directory, and now all bash scripts are gone. I still have one tab opened in terminator which seems to have bash history. What can I do to restore it? When new tabs are created in the terminal, it looks broken.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 ...

Comment: [21.04 is EOL and off-topic here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19913/end-of-life-notice-ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-reached-end-of-life-on-january), but because this [applies to supported Ubuntu versions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19939/is-it-ok-to-edit-a-question-to-replace-the-ubuntu-spin-off-to-its-ubuntu-equival), I'd support re-opening it regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User10489's answer is more practical and probably should be explored first.

...But if that doesn't work out, (a slightly more nuclear option) you could always just make new user and copy your data files over. Your system is still there, you just somewhat broke that particular account...

Answer (score 0):

The lack of shell init files doesn't break anything, it just removes features you are probably accustomed to.  In particular, the history file doesn't help, it only contains past commands you've run.

You can recreate the shell init files manually, copy them from a backup of your home directory, or copy the defaults from `/etc/skel/`

Zsh may also have its own procedure for recreating these, so possibly logging in again my trigger that.